# Automatically move data from swap to ram once enough memory is free

Tags: linux, memory, swap

Yes I know there are already questions that ask the same thing. **But none of the answers actually answer the question**.

One common answer is "you don't need to be concerned aboput it, because swap being used doesn't mean that something is actively being swapped in/out". This answer is technically right, but if something is in swap, this means that trying to use some of the currently running programs is going to be very slow. And these issues persist for hours after I closed the program that caused swapping in the first place.

Other common answer is "turn swap off an on". This is manual solution, and it can be a bit risky. Even if I check that I actually have enough free memory, If I start some memory consuming program while doing this, things will most likely go wrong.

So my question is, is there any way to automate it that won't break as soon as I start memory-consuming program while it's moving data from swap to ram?

Comment: Why would you want the system to do the extra work of paging in all that data when no program is currently using it, and may never? you are going from a situation where you MIGHT encounter a performance drag when paging data back in when it is needed at runtime, to a situation where you WILL experience that same drag, but this time its guaranteed to happen, and is not in direct response to an immediate need. To waste resources doing it now, just because you might need it later seems unwise. Is it better to burn your money now because it MIGHT catch fire at some unspecified date in the future?

Comment: It seems like doing it now instead of when some program needswouldn't affect performance as much. When some program needs it, it needs it immediately to continue working. Doing it in the background can be done at lower priority (if it's possible), without noticably affecting performance. And after quitting some program that used several GB of memory it's 100% certain that I will experience performance issues with every single currently running program whenever I try to use it.

Comment: so how do you determine when it is best to do it in the background? thats much more complicated than simply retrieving disk pages when physical ram frees up. I'd argue that if you are that taxed on performance, that its probably time to bump up your RAM, as you are forcing more paging than is really a good idea byu having too little (or trying to do too much with it).

Comment: Closing and reopening whatever program you are using would be one option. Benefit there is you can be highly selective about what gets loaded back in.

Comment: When that option would be eabled - do it always when there is enough free memory and no program is swapping anythiing out, and cpu usage isn't too high. That's what I would consider as "doing something in the background". This is really major issue for me when I run some memory consuming program, close it and then even hours later performance of some programs is still bad because of that.

Comment: And closing the program that needs it is only possible when it's already responsive enough. And it usually isn't until a lot of memory is moved back into ram. There are also many situations when a big chunk of memory is in swap until I use a specific option in some program, there is no way for me to "guess" what I need to do do move it to ram.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-re-load-all-running-applications-from-swap-space-into-ram

Comment: There are several answers there that seem to be different approaches to what you want, pity we can't close as a cross site dupe...

Comment: @Mokubai The second answer to that seems like a good idea... but python script... When using the first answer I need to be sure that I won't use any memory consuming program while going that. And since this is a laptop, getting more memory isn't that easy. And usually the 8GB I have is enough, except in some specific situations.

Comment: The Python answer is coded so you pass it process ids, it sounds like *exactly* what you were asking. Find your process id, then slurp it back in. You can be entirely selective.

Comment: I guess that's the closest thing I can get. By running it on all processes started by me (ie. not root processes) with high niceness value, it should be able to do what I want.